# Best way to get first coincidence in two strings

Tags: php

I have two timestamps

```
$now = time(); // 1689548338
$old = strtotime('-2 week'); // 1688338738
```

How I can to get first coincidence?

Like: `$result == 168`
Or: `$result == "168"`

Solution FROM Chat GPT

```
$now = (string) time(); // Convert to string
$old = (string) strtotime('-2 week'); // Convert to string

$length = min(strlen($now), strlen($old)); // Find the minimum length

$result = ""; // Initialize the result variable

// Iterate over the characters of the timestamps
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if ($now[$i] !== $old[$i]) {
        break; // Break the loop if a different character is found
    }

    $result .= $now[$i]; // Append the character to the result
}

// Output the result
echo $result;
```

And it's works for me. But maybe in php we can do it without loop just some php function or so?

Comment: Nope, O(n) is the minimum available complexity, cause anyway you need to iterate all elements